# Backpack for laravel - inline-create many-to-many relation

Tags: laravel-backpack

I am using Laravel BackPack Pro and I can't get full modal form for *inline-create* relation... It was working early, but after some coding and updates I found that this feature dosen't work any more with no any errors =\

My main model is **Image**, which has **Tags** (many-to-many) and **Category** (belongs-to) related models

[image: settings for create operation for images]

**Category** inline-create still working! But **tags** - not.
I have no any errors, but the response of modal request - returns with only initial form, buttons  and with NO any fields:

[image: NO any fields, only buttons]

Common tag **create** action is Ok, and I did't rewrite any modal views.

Can someone explain what can be wrong?

Comment: upd: if I use $this->crud->setFromDb(); in tag crud controller, it works good.
but my manually setupCreateOperation() is pretty simply and have no errors =\

Comment: Please show the code

Answer (score 0):

Ok, I got it!
My setup **tag crud controller** was

```
public function setup() {
   ...
   $this->crud->operation(['create', 'update'], function () {
      ...
   }  
}
```

But when I exclude **create** operation to separate method

```
protected function setupCreateOperation() {
   ...
}
```

all started working as expected!

Comment: I guess you found an inconsistency, I will open an issue for it.
Inline create only calls the `setupCreateMethod` but does not get the setup from callbacks.

Comment: Yes, I think ti is issue too, because it is unexpected =\  I use $this->crud->operation(['create', 'update'] for DRY purpose and got other behaviour

Comment: Thanks for the explanation and sorry for the bad experience. I've sent a PR to fix this, should be tagged in the next version that will launch in the next days.